# Convert Tensorflow model into Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a problem with the conversion of the tensorflow model to tflite. 
I have a learned model based on [Tensorflow Object Detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)
I would like to use the conversion code from [TFlite converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples)

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_0.50_128_frozen.tgz | tar xzv -C /tmp

tflite_convert \
 --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite \
 --graph_def_file=/tmp/mobilenet_v1_0.50_128/frozen_graph.pb \
 --input_arrays=input \
 --output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

I do not know where to get value of input_arrays and output_arrays.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

We have [a script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py) in the Object Detection API to get the Flatbuffer.

Comment: it looks like of conversion in the repo is done via CLI (based on me seeing your answer, and some documentation/ readme's). But I've seen that the python scripts are recommended over the CLI, yet I have not seen good examples for conversion in python. I am left confused. 

Answer (score 0):

If you download the model from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md) then there will be a file mobilenet_v1_0.5_128_info.txt which states the input and output name

```
Model: mobilenet_v1_0.5_128
Input: input
Output: MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way i found is to upload my model to https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/ it shows the inputs and outputs of any model.

p.s it also has a [desktop app](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron#install) that i use, instead of uploading every model